# Flask doesnt'see uploaded file

Tags: javascript, python, flask

I have this simple html:

```
<input class="input" type="file" name="file" id="imageInp"></input>
<button class="addBtn" id="addBtn">Add</button>
```

And this JS:

```
var HttpClient = function () {
  this.get = function (aUrl, img) {
    var anHttpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var fdata = new FormData();
    fdata.append("file", img);

    anHttpRequest.open("POST", aUrl, true);
    anHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "multipart/form-data");
    anHttpRequest.send(fdata);
  }
}

document.getElementById("addBtn").onclick = function() { 
  image = document.getElementById("imageInp").files[0];
  var client = new HttpClient();
  client.get(*url_here*, image);
}
```

And this code in flask:

```
@app.route('*url_here*', methods=['POST'])
def foo():
  try:
    print(request.form)
    print(request.files)
    print(request.data)
    frame = request.files['file'].read()
    
    return 'OK', 200, {'ContentType':'application/json'}

  except Exception as e:
    log('Main', e)
    return 'Error', 400, {'ContentType':'application/json'}
```

And when I use that all I see this:

```
ImmutableMultiDict([])
ImmutableMultiDict([])
b''
400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.
```

So, flask doesn't see my file. How can I fix it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are using JavaScript in this case rather than HTML alone?

Comment: @Daweo it's minimal example. I have some additional things in bigger but it doesn't matter for this file upload.

Comment: Ok, then please consider adding `javascript` tag to your question

Comment: @Daweo added. But I checked how JS part works and I saw that form data has right entries.

Answer (score 0):

Found solution here: [Upload files to Flask server via xhr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69149950/upload-files-to-flask-server-via-xhr)

It's strange. I saw another questions where people recommended using this header.